# Drop tables where the last update is over 1 week ago

Tags: mysql

I can see in PMA that it stores information for every table. 
[image]

I was wondering if there was an SQL query to drop any table in the database that have a last update time of more than 1 week ago?

Comment: What do you mean ***last update time***. 1.When the table structure was changed or 2.When was the last entry done.

Answer (score 2):

All the metadata about tables are stored in the db named [information_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html).

Try this:

```
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME
FROM
    information_schema.TABLES
WHERE 
    UPDATE_TIME < (NOW()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

**UPDATE:** i forgot to mention this will get you all the tables that you need to drop, after that you can build the `DROP` statements.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below Query:

```
select CONCAT('drop table ',TABLE_NAME)
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where update_time < (now()-interval 1 week)
```

**[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated)**

Additionally, you may add the above query to a prepared statements in order to execute the drop(s) as is shown in the **[answer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053116/mysql-bulk-drop-table-where-table-like)**

Comment: This doesn't drop the table, but instead you just create a result containing `drop table` in all the rows.

Comment: @meewoK Do we have to write the SP too? I don't like to spoon feed, hence i have given Pseudo code.

Comment: ok good point. Editing to just add a reference to Prepared Statement. Argh...when the edit goes through I can reverse that -1...

Comment: @meewoK I have edited the post. Thanks for your information,

Comment: Your query is wrong. You should use CONCAT(). In MySQL + doesn't concatenate strings.

Comment: @Federico I think my update answer will satisfy you.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can use a Stored Procedure which queries the `information_schema` and composes the `DROP TABLE`s dynamically.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.drop_old_tables()
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    COMMENT 'Drops tables older than 1 week'
BEGIN
    DECLARE `eof` BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE `db_name` VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE `tab_name` VARCHAR(64);

    DECLARE `crs_old_tabs` CURSOR FOR
        SELECT
                `TABLE_SCHEMA`, `TABLE_NAME`
            FROM
                `information_schema`.`TABLES`
            WHERE 
                `UPDATE_TIME` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK);

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
        FOR NOT FOUND
    BEGIN
        SET `eof` = TRUE;
    END;

    `lbl_old_tabs`:
    LOOP
        FETCH NEXT FROM `crs_old_tabs` INTO `db_name`, `tab_name`;

        IF `eof` IS TRUE THEN
            LEAVE `lbl_old_tabs`;
        END IF;

        SET @sql_drop = CONCAT('DROP TABLE `', REPLACE(`db_name`, '`', '``'), '`.`', REPLACE(`tab_name`, '`', '``'), '`;');
        PREPARE stmt_drop;
        EXECUTE stmt_drop;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_drop;
    END LOOP;

    SET @sql_drop = NULL;
END;
```

I didn't try this procedure, so it's possible that you'll have to fix one error or two.